# Custom Theme on Dialog Box

Tags: android, eclipse, api

I'd searched for a custom dialog box and I found that adding theme is one way of customizing the `alertdialog` and whenever I add `android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar` on my `AlertDialog`. My program forces to close when running. and I receive `Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder` Do I need to install API level 11?

My API is from 8 to 19.

heres my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
     builder.setTitle("Exit");
     builder.setMessage("Do you want to quit the game?");
     builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          dialog.dismiss();
          finish();
                }
            });
     builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
}
```

what should I need to use this different kind of theme?

please apologize my question thank you guys

Comment: Have you considered setting #minSdkVersion14? Is there are a reason you need to target lower APIs?

Comment: to make my program compatible for those lower level api?

Comment: There isn't a large market share on Gingerbread any more - https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html , though obviously it's a case by case basis whether you decide target >= ICS

Comment: Also worth noting that API 14 is already (almost) 3 years old: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all why you are creating objects twice:-

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
```

Next is you maybe debugging your app on device which is less than HoneyComb **(API 11)** . But the **AlertDialog.Builder (Context context, int theme)** Added in API level 11. So for the versions < 11 , you can use

```
Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new   
     ContextThemeWrapper(this,android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog));
```

Comment: sir @rahul I tried and there are no changes in the dialog. how was that?

Comment: @user3691945 Did u replaced this style with your style. can you show me code